# Convert latitude and longitude coordinates to NMEA (DDDMM.MM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps, coordinates, nmea

I am building a GPS emulator that will simulate a tracking device. The server accepts latitude and longitude in in NMEA 0183 standard (DDDMM.MM). I need a JavaScript function that does this.

For example:

latitude: 55.743375 should be  5544.6025N
Longitude:37.66139 should be 03739.6834E

I could not find any examples to do this. all the examples are on converting NMEA format to Decimal

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/jamesp/node-nmea

Comment: NMEA is just degree and minutes (minutes can be decimal number), much more similar to the best way to describe latitude and longitude (I would use degree, minute and seconds, for real geographic coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

***Python code***:

```
def cn(gps): # gps as string
    gps = float(gps)        # string to float
    intc = int(gps)  # integer part of float value
    dc = gps - intc         # fractional part
    ngps = (intc * 100) + (dc * 60)
    return ngps
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).